# Svndump with repository version

Tags: svn, bash, batch-file, tortoisesvn

I need to create a backup script (both in batch and bash) which I want to make an automatic svndump which creates the filename dump `<repository_name>_<repository_rev>.zip`.

Example:
My repository name is MySplice and it's on rev. 234 (which I don't know and I don't wanna check inside repository path), so I want to run a script `backup.bat` or `backup.sh` and it creates the file `mysplice_r234.zip`, which is the dump of my repository.

So, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: As you know svndump you can create your dump file, compress it with 7z or zip and rename it. What do you tried till now? Which part fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux you could do it this way:

```
REPO=/path/to/repository
r=$(svnlook youngest "$REPO")
name=$(basename "$REPO")-r$r
svnadmin dump "$REPO" > "$name.svndump"
zip "$name.zip" "$name.svndump"
```

Please note: I think, that a zip file is not a good fit for a repository, because the dump will always be exectly one file and not a bunch of files. So please consider using `gzip` or `bzip2` instead.

Comment: +1. Note that **svnlook youngest $REPO/subproj** does not work, but **svn info file://$REPO/subproj** do job... This can be useful for multiproject hierarchy in single REPO...

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works perfectly for my repositories. I use Windows, but since cygwin is active, I can bash it. I also appreciated the gzip suggestion. The final script version I posted too.

Answer (score 2):

This is right solution (ever A.H. downvote answer to **-1**):

```
 $ rev=`svn info file:///srv/svn/proj | sed -n '/Last Changed Rev:/{s=.*: ==;p;q;}'`
 $ svnadmin dump /srv/svn/proj >proj-r$rev.dump
```

Proof for **A.H.** that he miss:

```
desktop+bash# svnadmin.exe create g
desktop+bash# svn co file://$PWD/g w
Checked out revision 0.
desktop+bash# cd w
/home/user/tmp/gg/w
desktop+bash# echo XXX >>README
desktop+bash# svn add README
A         README
desktop+bash# svn ci -m up
Adding         README
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1.
desktop+bash# cd ..
desktop+bash# svn info file://$PWD/g
Path: g
URL: file:///home/user/tmp/gg/g
Repository Root: file:///home/user/tmp/gg/g
Repository UUID: 38434ae0-ea0a-41ac-9891-55099858d224
Revision: 1
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: user
Last Changed Rev: 1
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-05 16:30:27 +0200 (Сб, 05 ноя 2011)
```

Comment: Won't work because `svn info` can work only on a working copy, not on a repository.

Comment: @A.H. I make mistake when write answer from head... Look again. SVN version 1.7. Just add **file://**

Comment: Thanks for fixing the repository path into an repository URL.

Comment: Your solution also fits very well. I prefered using the @A.H. one because it's simpler to be maintained by other guys. But I learned much studying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your responses. I chose to use the following script based in @A.H. solution:

```
#backup_repos.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
export REPO=$1
export r=$(svnlook youngest "$REPO")
export name=$(basename "$REPO")-r$r-`date +%Y.%m.%d`

svnadmin dump "$REPO" > "$name-dump"
gzip -f "$name-dump"
```

Answer (score 0):

SubWCRev (Windows-only, from TSVN) can extract RevisionInfo *from WC*, write it to file (using some macros). You can have *template of bat-file*, which SubWCRev will converts for *final-form bat-file* and run **this file**.

I use this method for exporting (WC) into dir with revision-timestamp in name

Comment: I didn't know this fuctionality of TortoiseSVN. Good to know it, I shall study it more soon. Thank you.